# Issue using UI Skins from the Xamarin Component Store

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

When I download a skin from the Component store, then try to use it, I am doing it using the Unified/Universal layouts/platform.  I am getting this error:

MTOUCHTASK: error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Void UIKit.UINavigationBar::SetTitleTextAttributes(UIKit.UITextAttributes)" reference from "Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065"

It is happening with all skins.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my solution: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41261911/testForUIChange.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the dates (Jan 11th) you were probably using an beta version of XI 8.6 along with the component from the store (which always target **stable**, 8.4).

There were some difference between the unified **preview** (in 8.4) and the final version of the API (shipped with 8.6). That make it harder to find the right *binary* component to match.

As of today (Jan 12th 2015) Xamarin.iOS 8.6 is stable, has the final unified API and the component store has updated *most* of the components (some 3rd parties might not yet be available right now) to the *final* unified API.

IOW there's a good chance you can update your components (if you were already on 8.6) or all your software (if you were not on 8.6) and get a working build.

Comment: It is now working.  I learned the same thing today, I forgot to mark this as resolved.  Thanks for your support!